# Java - explicit conversion to char/short

Tags: java

can anyone tell me why this explicit conversion gives different results, even if size of short/char is both 16bits?

```
package jh;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     byte b = (byte)255;

     System.out.println("Size of short: " + Short.SIZE);
     System.out.println("Size of char: " + Character.SIZE);

     System.out.println((int)((short)b));
     System.out.println((int)((char)b));        
   }
 }
```

**Output:**

```
Size of short: 16
Size of char: 16
-1
65535
```

Comment: The old **byte is signed** stuff again, with sign extension...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Java datatypes doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> **byte:** The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of **-128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive)**. The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.
>
> **short:** The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of **-32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767 (inclusive)**. As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.
>
> **char:** The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of **'\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive)**.

So in *short* (pardon the pun), **bitwise they are the same**. But `char` represents a different *numeric value* for the same bit pattern as `short`.

This is also accompanied by the sign extension feature: `(byte) 255` is going to mean a byte value, with all bits set (`0b11111111`), which is -1, in [twos complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). When converting upwards, Java does a sign extension operation, so if the sign bit is 0, all the higher bits will be 0 too, but when the sign bit is 1, all higher bits will be 1 too. This now means that -1 will mean -1 in all signed, integer datatypes (`0b1111111111111111` for `short` in this example). But not char - which when has all bits set, equals the positive maximum value - 65535.

Comment: ok so only if i am converting from unsigned to signed, remaining space is filled up with '0' bit, otherweise with last bit of converted value?

Comment: @Krab: not from unsigned to signed, but when from a smaller datatype to a larger one. (BTW, char is _the only_ unsigned type in Java) And it will be filled with the value in the MSB. So if the value is like 0b1xxxxxxx, then it will become 0b111111111xxxxxxx, and if the value is like 0b0xxxxxxx, then it will become 0b000000000xxxxxxx....

Comment: but if it is always filled up with the value in MSB, then converting from char = MAX_VALUE to int should give -1, but gives char MAX_VALUE, so it must be filled up with '0', even if MSB of char MAX_VALUE is '1'

Comment: @Krab: you're right, I didn't think it through enough when I wrote that. Most types have the sign bit at the MSB. Char behaves a little bit different than any other types: char is unsigned, so the sign bit is always treated to be 0, and not the MSB value. It's my mistake: instead of _MSB_ I should have written _sign bit_ to be correct for all cases.

Answer (score 3):

`byte` is signed and only holds values `-128..127`. When you assign 255 it wraps around and becomes `-1`.

`(short)b` is `-1`.

`char` however is the only unsigned type in Java, it has values `0..65535`, so `(char)-1` wraps around again and becomes `65535`.

Answer (score 0):

`byte b = (byte)255;` this assigns the value -1 to `b` since `byte` is signed. When you cast -1 to `short` you get -1. When you cast -1 to `char` you get 65535 since the range of `char` lies between 0 and 65535